# How to set viewport only for iphone or ipad?

Tags: iphone, viewport

I have a website that needs to use 0.3 value for viewport on iphone, but 0.7 for ipad.

Is there a way to set viewport for only iphone or ipad?

Comment: If you are not happy with answers you got, please comment on them so people can try to improve them. If you are, accept one of them.

Comment: @fichek in this case, no answers here answer the OP's question. This includes your own answer. Before asking the OP to respond, re-read the question : )

Answer (score 29):

Here is one solution...

```
<!-- in head -->
<meta id="viewport" name='viewport'>
<script>
    (function(doc) {
        var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
        if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
            viewport.setAttribute("content", "initial-scale=0.3");
        } else if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ) {
            viewport.setAttribute("content", "initial-scale=0.7");
        }
    }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: I see you are using an IIFE, could the function expression wrapper be eliminated and the effect be the same? What is the benefit of the IIFE format in this case?

Comment: The IIFE is to manage scope, so any variables declared within the IIFE don't pollute the global scope (such as `viewport`)

Comment: Plus one for a non-jQuery solution, even though I'm using jQuery. I want to make sure this runs as soon as computerly possible.

Answer (score 10):

I found a simple way with jQuery!

Add this to the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<script>if ($(window).width() < 600) { $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','initial-scale=0.54, maximum-scale=0.54, user-scalable=no'); }</script>
```

The `<meta>` tag sets the default scale and the `<script>` tag re-writes the viewport if the device screen width is less than 600 pixels (I think all phone devices are under 600px).

I could not find a simple solution anywhere so I came up with this :)

Comment: The iPhone initially sets the window width to 960px.

Answer (score 8):

Please note, `meta viewport` is comma-delimited list, you should not use semicolons.

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320,
       initial-scale = 2.3, user-scalable = no">
```

Source:
[viewport syntax in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193) and 
[Configuring the Viewport – Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW26)

*(If I had more reputation points, I would add this as a comment)*

Comment: Now you've enough reputation to add comment :)

Answer (score 5):

For all mobile devices, try something like this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (/iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|opera mini|opera mobi|skyfire|maemo|windows phone|palm|iemobile|symbian|symbianos|fennec/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
    $("meta[name='viewport']").attr("content", "width=640");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

> If you need to set different viewport, based on the
>   device(iPhone/iPad), you need to set the viewport using device-width
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; width=device-width;">
> ```
>
> What the above statement will do is set a viewport of 320px on iPhone
>   and 768px on the iPad..Guess that is what woudld translate into 0.3
>   and 0.7 u are looking for..

This worked but only **after** I realized that this line does not go in the ... section! Dumb of me, but maybe needs to be said.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That script from Tim that uses jquery seems to work well. I changed it a little bit and it seems to work for me. I added some scale parameters. It gave me the results I needed for my page display well on both iphone and ipad. Here is what I added:

```
maximum-scale=2.0; user-scalable=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can set a viewport for only iPhone but you could set the media query and thus the CSS for only iPhone I think.

By setting the media query for only device widths of the iPhone (320x480) or iPad (1024x768) you could possibly achieve what you're trying for.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer below on how to dynamically set your initial-zoom so that your entire site is zoomed correctly on page load (works for all device sizes).

[Change tablet viewport to exactly show fixed dimension element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523029/change-tablet-viewport-to-exactly-show-fixed-dimension-element/15983814#15983814)