# Twitter bootstrap - Disable responsive only for tablets

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using twitter bootstrap 3 for a site design.  I am looking for a way to disable the responsiveness on tablets but keep them for mobile phones.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787304/how-to-set-viewport-only-for-iphone-or-ipad. You'll have to read through them. There's others out there too. Basically you'd only load the viewport meta tag for mobile phones, remove the iPad from that list: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16345269/1004312. Sniffing is not reliable, there's always new devices coming out. Better to use server side technology, like https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect then between the if variable, call the viewport tag

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to create Bootstrap's Grid lay-out, take a look here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

This is an example grid for "Mobile and desktop", and I believe this is exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I am asking how to only enable the responsive grid design when the page is viewed on a mobile device.  I am not asking how to design a grid layout

Comment: So you want a percentage-based lay-out for mobile and fixed for tablets and desktop? Then you should take a look at Bootstrap's Media Queries in the css and change the percentages to pixels for those.